# Regarding quota percentage in counter booking

Tags: trains, india, indian-railways

Somebody told me that on Indian Railways, 60% of seats are reserved for counter bookings and 40% for online bookings.  Is this correct or not?  Because while I am checking seat availabilty on the Internet, no seats are available, but when I went to ask at a ticket counter, berths are available.

Comment: You need to check mainly from railway official site whether the seats are available or not you can clarify your doubts regarding train seats availability so that whether seats booking status you can check <a href="http://www.cbse10thresults-2019.xyz/2019/12/cbse-10th-results-2020.html">that</a>

Answer (score 5):

Indian Railways has approximately 1 bazillion different quotas (Tatkal, Foreign Tourist, Handicapped, Ladies, ...), but as far as I'm aware, **online bookings are *not* one of them**: both ticket counter and online bookings use the same quotas.  If you're getting different answers online and in person, you're presumably looking at different quotas/tickets/trains/classes?

For more about the algorithm, [this Quora answer](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-algorithm-used-to-reserve-ticket-in-Indian-Railways) goes into far more detail than I can attempt to summarize.

Answer (score 5):

Indian railways is having many quotas. There are 18 in total as listed [here](https://pnrstatuslive.com/what-are-quotas-in-indian-railways)

1. GN  General Quota
2. LD  Ladies Quota
3. HO  Head quarters/high official Quota
4. DF  Defence Quota
5. PH  Parliament house Quota
6. FT  Foreign Tourist Quota
7. DP  Duty Pass Quota
8. CK  Tatkal Quota
9. SS  Female(above 45 Year)/Senior Citizen/Travelling alone
10. HP  Physically Handicapped Quota
11. RE  Railway Employee Staff on Duty for the train
12. GNRS    General Quota Road Side
13. OS  Out Station
14. PQ  Pooled Quota
15. RC(RAC)     Reservation Against Cancellation
16. RS  Road Side
17. YU  Yuva
18. LB  Lower Berth

Out of these only 4 quotas can be booked online (premium tatkal is not a seperate quota. So it is not listed here). They are

> General Quota
>
> Ladies Quota
>
> Tatkal Quota
>
> Physically Handicapped Quota

So if you are booking on a different quota, for example Foreign Tourist Quota then you can buy the tickets in counter while your online booking may say `no tickets are available`.

There is no seperate quotas for online booking and counter booking. It is just that you cannot book some quotas online.

Comment: You can book a ticket under the Foreign tourist quota online, if you're a Person of Indian origin (OCI) / a foreigner. You need to register using your overseas mobile number & carry passport confirming that you're a foreigner / NRI/ OCI person. Ticket prices & cancellation charges are slightly higher for this quota.